Can I stream audio from Spotify from an authenticated user to another user which is not authenticated with Spotify? (Web/React)
I have this feature that is crucial for our product. It is a platform where two types of users(healers and clients) meet and have a spiritual session together.
We would like to let the 'healers' integrate(connect) their Spotify account within our platform and choose a playlist to their taste, which will later be played during the healing session which is a video meeting (using Dyte as WebRTC provider) for both them and the clients. The thing is, the 'client' is not authenticated with Spotify, and still he should hear the same audio the 'healer' is hearing. Any way we can somehow propagate the audio from the healer to the client, so they hear the same audio track at the same time?
Note: I'm using React TSX and Spring Boot Java.
I've tried connecting healer with Spotify, and then just fetching the spotify track URL and putting it into client's  player, but it didn't work.
P.S: Most of our clients use iPhone, meaning they'll probably use Safari too, so the ideal solution for me would be something that would work on mobile and desktop too.

You could capture the audio via getDisplayMedia().

From the spotify terms & conditions: "You agree that you will not redistribute or transfer the Spotify Service or the Content.". So maybe don't ask for help trying to break those terms. :)

Ah, must've missed that. So it is not legal to do it whatsoever, correct?

Just have your healers and clients use headphones and share their music over a phone call. So much easier.

Unfortunately, the session is being held via Dyte which is a video/meeting provider integrated within our application. What I had as an idea is maybe get Spotify's audio output on healer side and somehow plug that audio stream into the video provider as an audio track (basically simulating that this audio comes from the microphone of the healer), although I'd need to do a research if thats possible at all.
